# React - how to replace useCallback hook with useMemo?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-usememo, react-usecallback

I am reading this [article](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/memoization-in-javascript-and-react/#javascript-memoization-example) about memoization in React, and I wonder how can I translate and use `useMemo` instead of `useCallback` hook. In particular for this example:

```
<Child name={ useCallback(() => {console.log('Really Skinny Jack')}, [])  } />
```

Where Child component looks like this:

```
export default React.memo(function Child({ name }) {
  console.log("Child component");
  return (
    <>
      {name()}
      <div>Child component</div>
    </>
  );
});
```

If I try to replace this with `useMemo`:

```
  <Child
    name={useMemo(() => {
      console.log("useMemo");
    }, [])}
  />
```

I get an error:

```
TypeError name is not a function
```

I also tried like this:

```
  {useMemo(
    <Child
      name={() => {
        console.log("useMemo");
      }}
    />,
    []
  )}
```

But, then I get:

```
TypeError nextCreate is not a function
```

So, I how am I suppose to replace `useCallback` with `useMemo` in this example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `useMemo`, you can do it like this

```js
<Child
  name={useMemo(() => {
    // return the function or anything you want react to memoize
    return () => {
      console.log('useMemo');
    };
  }, [])}
/>
```

With `useMemo`, whatever you return from the `useMemo`'s callback will be memoized. On the other hand, `useCallback` is used to memoize functions only.

Some key differences to note

### `useMemo`

Used to memoize functions, arrays, objects, etc.

```js
const memoizedList = useMemo(() => {
  return [1, 2, 3];
}, []);

const memoizedFunction = useMemo(() => {
  return () => {
    console.log('I am meoized');
  };
}, []);
```

### `useCallback`

Used to memoize functions

```js
const memoizedFunction = useCallback(() => {
  console.log('I am meoized');
}, []);
```

### `React.memo`

A Higher-Order Component to memoize React components

```js
const MyComponent = (props) => {
  return "I am a memoized component";
}
export default React.memo(MyComponent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace it like this

```
<Child name={React.useMemo(() => () => alert(55), [])} />
```

Answer (score 0):

> So, I how am I suppose to replace useCallback with useMemo in this
> example?

The `useCallback` hook returns a memoized callback function that is passed to it whereas the `useMemo` hook takes a function callback and returns a memoized value.

From the [`useCallback`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback) docs:

> `useCallback(fn, deps)` is equivalent to `useMemo(() => fn, deps)`.

The following are equivalent implementations:

1. `useCallback`

   ```
   const nameHandler = useCallback(() => {
     console.log('Really Skinny Jack');
   }, []);
   ...
   <Child name={nameHandler} />
   ```
2. `useMemo`

   ```
   const nameHandler = useMemo(() => () => {
     console.log('Really Skinny Jack');
   }, []);
   ...
   <Child name={nameHandler} />
   ```

The `useMemo` hook is taking a callback that ***returns*** a function that is being used and passed as a callback to a child component.

It isn't really clear at all *why* you would want to do this though. The `useCallback` hook is the intended hook to be used when you want to memoize a callback that is passed to children components. It's also a lot clearer and easier to read than the "double" function that is used in the `useMemo` version. I suggest sticking to the `useCallback` version of your code.